# Create a vector (with cut line) for a shape that has an outline

Tags: vector, svg

For the following image (as an example), which is currently a PNG image, I need to convert the image into a vector with a cut line for a label printer to use, such that I would end up with a triangular label that has a red circle inside it.

I have tried a few online tools and have downloaded Inkscape, but cannot see how to achieve what I need; the closest that I get is a path around ALL of the shapes, including the outside (blue) box; that would result in a square label, with a triangular label in the middle and a circle in the middle of that ... without any of the colour.

The description that I was given for a specification was a vector image, with pink cut lines

I hope that makes sense and that someone can assist.

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to redraw the triangle in a design program such as Illustrator or CorelDraw. Set the triangle with a stroke and stroke colour should be 100% Magenta (C0 M100 Y0 K0) to create the vector line required by the label printer. Save the image as an SVG, or just send your label printer the design file.

If you don’t have a design program, you could use an online vector conversion service such as [**Vector Magic**](http://vectormagic.com/home), the result should be fine for such a simple shape. [Printco labels](http://www.printco.ie/printing/stickers/labels/index.html) also has some useful artwork set up resources to keep in mind.

Comment: Not really a solution, but I found an online conversion which did the job. Re-draw in the image wasn't an option; I only mentioned the triangle as an example - my images are actually far more complicated and would take ages to re-draw from scratch.